# How to make "drop down" menu?

Tags: drop-down-menu

I know there have been a million questions asking this, but mine is different.  I don't want to just make a navigation bar that you can hover over and view sublevels.  I want the actual navigation bar (which I have as an image) to come in from out of sight.  What would be the best way to go about this?  Coding, Flash, CSS?

Comment: can you expand on this question. it isn't clear what you are asking. Provide an example?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? www.mattvarone.com/web-design/css-text-based-navigation-bar-with-images/

Comment: I don't have a specific example, but I've been to websites where they have a bar at the bottom that can be "minimized" or brought up.  Inside bar lies links to various things.  I've seen it on a bunch of sites, but I can't find one now.  Anyways, I want something similar to that.

Comment: Minimized is a javascript thing. You need to write `toggle()` , or `show()`, `hide()` functions. I don't understand the second part, however. Maybe jquery is a choice to go.

Comment: Somewhat, but I want the navigation bar to be hidden until the user hovers over a certain area.  Once they do that, the navigation bar slides down into view.

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin I think javascript is the way to go. There MIGHT be some CSS hacks to hide and show with mouse hover (I would be really shock to see that...). Google navigation bar hide show hover. You can use pure JS, or instead, go for jQuery. It's has all those functions ready for you to use. JS is really for action, and CSS is only for styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using a hover event to show a navigation bar can be very difficult for users to use, though is does save valuable screen space to have it hide. If you choose to stick with the navigation that shows after a hover event, keep it very basic.

Check out this link, it uses the same idea... but uses a click instead. Just change it to work with hover instead.

Hope this fixes your problem!

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/expandable-collapsible-toggle-pane-jquery.html